# How do I implement IUpdatable Service

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am sorry if this is a newbie question, but I am new to C# programming.

But I am trying to write a WCF data service and it reads data and spits out an odata feed just fine. I added the service reference in VS which created service types and data models for me, but I seem to be missing a `SaveChanges()` method (which I see being called in a bunch of tutorials.)

This has lead me to `IUpdatable`, the current stop down the rabbit hole. What does it mean when someone says "your service doesn't support updates because it doesn't implement `IUpdatable`." How to I implement this interface? What does it even mean to implement this interface?

Also, this is for a Windows Phone app.

Comment: This is a little surprising to me if my understanding of your problem is correct. At "Add Service Reference" (ASR) time, I don't think the client does any special checks to see whether the service is read/write (it would actually have to POST to the service to test this). So in theory it should ALWAYS generate the SaveChanges() method regardless of the service implementing IUpdatable. Can you give us more detail here? What versions of Visual Studio, Windows Phone SDK and WCF Data Services are you using? How did you generate the service reference?

Comment: I am using VS2010 Ultimate, Windows Phone SDK 7.1, not sure what version of WCF Data Services I am using. How would I find that out? The way I added my WCf Service is I right clicked on Referecnces, clicekd on Add Service Reference, entered in my WCF Data Service .scv url, Typed in a Namespace and clicked ok. It then geenerated the datasvcmap and .cs files for me.

Comment: Sorry, the Windows Phone 7 bit just registered - the methods are async on WP7 and so they follow the common naming convention of `BeginSaveChanges` and `EndSaveChanges`. See the sample below.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows Phone 7 is Silverlight based and therefore required to be async, there is no `SaveChanges` method on the context but rather a `BeginSaveChanges` and `EndSaveChanges` method pair. You can call them like so:

```
private void SaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Start the saving changes operation.
    svcContext.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch, 
        OnChangesSaved, svcContext);
}

private void OnChangesSaved(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // Use the Dispatcher to ensure that the 
    // asynchronous call returns in the correct thread.
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            svcContext = result.AsyncState as NorthwindEntities;

            try
            {
                // Complete the save changes operation and display the response.
                WriteOperationResponse(svcContext.EndSaveChanges(result));
            }
            catch (DataServiceRequestException ex)
            {
                // Display the error from the response.
                WriteOperationResponse(ex.Response);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                messageTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the order in the grid.
                ordersGrid.SelectedItem = currentOrder;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

That sample is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521146(VS.92).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is not the missing SaveChanges method on the client (which Mark's answer above should solve), and you have authored a service which is supposed to support read-write access, then you might need to implement IUpdatable interface (on the server).

If your service uses EF provider, then this should already work as the EF provider implements IUpdatable out of the box.

If your service uses reflection provider, then you will need to implement IUpdatable over your context. There's some description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx.

If you are using a custom provider, then you will also need to implement the IUpdatable and there are samples of that as well, but I don't think you are going this route :-)

Answer (score 0):

IUpdatable is described by it's designers here:
[WCF Data Service Blog: IUpdatable & ADO.Net DataServices Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/10/iupdatable-ado-net-data-services-framework.aspx)